# Why am I getting NoMethodError with my rails app on AppFog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, appfog

I have a rails app on AppFog, connected to a mongo database. It is a very simple database, where I used the mongo_mapper gem to create MVC stuff, and then didn't modify it.

```
rails g scaffold Contacts name:string address:string email:string phone:string -orm mongo_mapper
```

REALLY basic! Just trying to test out mongo as a database.

I followed the instructions for talking with the database [here](https://docs.appfog.com/services/mongodb#ruby).

However, every time I try to access the `/contacts` path, I get a "500 Internal Server Error" message.

The AppFog logs for my app report:

```
Started GET "/contacts" for 50.193.89.38 at 2013-04-03 21:18:58 +0000
Processing by ContactsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `collection' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

The first chunk of my contacts controller file:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.json
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contacts }
    end
  end
....
```

Any help would be great.

**==UPDATE==**

```
$ rails console
irb(main):001:0> Contact.all
=> []
```

And using `rails s` works fine, I don't get the 500 error at all.

Comment: In console, what do you get when you try `Contact.all`?

Comment: `irb(main):002:0> Contact.all`
`=> []`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the model should be singular, ie `Contact`and not `Contacts`.

`rails g scaffold Contact name:string address:string email:string phone:string -orm mongo_mapper`

The way you created, makes the name of the model be `Contacts` and not `Contact`. So when you try `Contact.all` you get `nil`.